# Use walrus operator in Python 3.7

Tags: python, python-import

Why are future imports limited to only certain functionality? Is there no way to get the walrus operator in Python 3.7? I thought this would work, but it doesn't:

```
from __future__ import walrus
```

It doesn't work because walrus isn't in the list of supported features:

```
__future__.all_feature_names
['nested_scopes', 'generators', 'division', 'absolute_import', 'with_statement', 'print_function', 'unicode_literals', 'barry_as_FLUFL', 'generator_stop', 'annotations']
```

Are there any other alternatives short of using python 3.8?

Comment: `Why are future imports limited to only certain functionality?`—Are you suggesting that every single new feature in every new version of Python should be retrospectively added to the previous versions?

Comment: _Why are future imports limited to only certain functionality?_ Please see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/323334/is-asking-why-on-language-specifications-still-considered-as-primarily-opinio.

Comment: @AMC I think that doesn't apply in this case, because what the OP is proposing is logically impossible, not a design decision; so answers can explain with facts and reasoning why it is impossible, not with opinions for why it might have been decided that way.

Comment: @kaya3 Ah, I see what you mean, I had read _Why are future imports limited to only certain functionality?_ as "Why/how were the features chosen".

Comment: It's not impossible to use the walrus operator with Python 3.7 but it requires you to write your own source code transformation via an import hook. This is of course not recommended for any serious code but it can be insightful for experimental purposes.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

If the version of Python you're using doesn't contain an implementation of a feature, then you cannot use that feature; writing `from __future__ import ...` cannot cause that feature to be implemented in the version of Python you have installed.

The purpose of `__future__` imports is to allow an "opt-in" period for new features which could break existing programs. For example, when the `/` operator's behaviour on integers was changed so that `3/2` was `1.5` instead of `1` (i.e. floor division), this would have broken a lot of code if it was just changed overnight. So *both* behaviours were implemented in the next few versions of Python, and if you were using one of those newer versions then you could choose the new behaviour with `from __future__ import division`. But you were only able to do so because the version of Python you were using *did* implement the new behaviour.

The walrus operator was introduced in Python 3.8, so if you are using a version prior to 3.8 then it does not contain an implementation of that operator, so you cannot use it. There was no need to use `__future__` to make the walrus operator "opt-in", since the introduction of a new operator with new syntax could not have broken any existing code.

Answer (score 20):

You can [read the PEP](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0236/) that introduced `__future__` for insight. Primarily,

> From time to time, Python makes an incompatible change to the advertised semantics of core language constructs, or changes their accidental (implementation-dependent) behavior in some way. While this is never done capriciously, and is always done with the aim of improving the language over the long term, over the short term it's contentious and disrupting.

The walrus operator is *not* a backwards-incompatible change: it changes nothing about the meaning of code that was already "working". `:=` was just a syntax error before.

So adding it to `__future__` was never even considered. You might object that, say, "with" statements were similarly brand new, but that's not entirely so:  "with" was not a reserved word, and its introduction could potentially break working code that used "with" as an identifier.

So, sorry, use 3.8 or you're out of luck. Don't shoot the messenger ;-)